# iOS - GooglePlus login

Tags: ios, google-plus

I'm trying to integrate google+ and for some reason:

```
[GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                        sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                               annotation:annotation]
```

Always return 0. I'm checked and copy/pasted the URL Types at least 100 times but the app logs in and I get the prompt from Google saying "This app wants permission ... " but when it goes back into the app, the delegate method is never called.

Comment: as Ian post says, how does your appdelegate and login vc class code look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact you're being returned to your app means your bundle ID custom URL is setup correctly, which is good. Check you have configured `GPPSignIn` before `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` is called, where you should have the `GPPURLHandler` call.

For example, if you set `[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID` in viewDidLoad of your main view, then it wont be set when the GPPURLHandler runs, so it wont be able to process your response. I would set it in your AppDelegate `application:didFinishLaunching:withOptions` or similar. If you're not sure, try logging out the basic properties on GPPSignIn in openURL, before you call `GPPURLHandler`.